# i want to modify this jquery script in such a way that it shows progress when a file is selected and not when it's submitted..any idea

Tags: jquery

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) {  
    if($('#userImage').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
            target:   '#targetLayer', 
            beforeSubmit: function() {
              $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total,                       percentComplete){   
                $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
        $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' +  percentComplete +' %</div>')
            },
            success:function (){
                $('#loader-icon').hide();
            },
            resetForm: true 
        }); 
        return false; 
    }
});
}); 

</script>
```

/**HTML**/

```
 <form id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" >
  <div>
  <label>Upload Image File:</label>
  <input name="userImage" id="userImage" type="file"
     class="demoInputBox"    multiple  />
     </div>
      <div><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" 
       value="Submit"  class="btnSubmit" /></div>
          <div id="progress-div"><div id="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <div id="targetLayer"></div>
         </form>
         <div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;">
           <img  src="LoaderIcon.gif" /></div>
```

i want to modify this script in such a way that it shows progress of the file when its selected and not when it's submitted...any idea...thanks in advance

Comment: can you post html as well

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solved it myself...i created an additional div and cloned the elements that loads within the div...i will post the code later perhaps if someone else encounter the same issue....